# Get-AzADAppPermission Id Translator

Tags: azure, permissions, azure-powershell, azure-app-registration

I'm running the `Get-AzADAppPermission` command to return a list of Web permissions a App registration has.

The output returns a GUID for the permissions.

How do I translate the output to English terms?

`Get-AzADAppPermission -ObjectId cbXXXX80-c841-XXXX-XXXX-0eXXXXXXX6d6`

Returns this:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***I tried to reproduce the same in my environment and got the results like below:***

I created an **Azure AD Application and granted API permissions**:

[image]

Now, I retrieved the **API permissions** by using the below command:

```bash
Connect-AzAccount

Get-AzADAppPermission -ObjectId ObjectID
```

[image]

To **get the name of the API permission by its GUID** try the below script:

```bash
$GraphPermissions = Get-AzureADServicePrincipal -Filter "DisplayName eq 'Microsoft Graph'"
$permissionId = "e1fe6dd8-ba31-4d61-89e7-88639da4683d" 
$permission = $GraphPermissions.Oauth2Permissions | Where-Object { $_.Id -eq $permissionId }
```

[image]

```bash
$GraphPermissions = Get-AzureADServicePrincipal -Filter "DisplayName eq 'Microsoft Graph'"
$permissionId = "0e263e50-5827-48a4-b97c-d940288653c7" 
$permission = $GraphPermissions.Oauth2Permissions | Where-Object { $_.Id -eq $permissionId }
```

[image]

The value of the GUID **`User.Read`** and **`Directory.AccessAsUser.All`** displayed successfully.

There is no direct command to fetch the Display Names of the API permissions using **`Get-AzADAppPermission`** .