# Insufficient privileges to complete the operation while data "azuread_group"

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, terraform-provider-azure

I am trying to read list of groups. I have logged in with service principle account
While running terraform script
this error occures

> GroupsClient.BaseClient.Get(): unexpected status 403 with OData error:
> Authorization_RequestDenied: Insufficient privileges to complete the
> operation.

```
data "azuread_group" "example" {
  display_name     = "all-users"
  security_enabled = true
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Could you include what API permissions or roles you granted for that service principal?

Comment: Which roles or permissions should be there?

Comment: You need to grant `Group.Read.All` API permission of **Application** type and make sure to grant **admin consent** to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The error occurs if the service principal does not have required permission *Group.Read.All* to perform the operation.

Initially, I too got **same error** when I ran your code without granting permissions to service principal:

```
data "azuread_group" "example" {
  display_name     = "group_name"
  security_enabled = true
}
```

**Response:**

[image]

To resolve the error, make sure to assign **`Group.Read.All`** permission of **Application** type to your service principal and grant **admin consent** to it:

[image]

In my case, I used below code to read the list of all **groups** and got response successfully after granting required permission to service principal:

```
data "azuread_groups" "all_groups" {
  return_all = true
}

output "groups" {
  value = data.azuread_groups.all_groups.display_names
}
```

**Response:**

[image]

Alternatively, you can also assign **Groups Administrator** role to your service principal like this:

[image]

**Reference:**
[azuread_groups | Data Sources | hashicorp/azuread | Terraform | Terraform Registry](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azuread/latest/docs/data-sources/groups#api-permissions)

Comment: I have granted the permisstion that you suggested, How to see through command all the permissions of  SP

Comment: You can refer this thread that contains PowerShell commands to fetch API  permissions granted to service principal https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76027751/get-azadapppermission-id-translator/76034994#76034994

Comment: I still see the same Insufficient privileges.

Comment: Could you confirm whether the admin consent is granted or not? Please include that API permissions screenshot from Portal by editing your quesstion?

Comment: Do I need to create app for reading groups?

Comment: Did you not meant app registration when you mentioned `I have logged in with service principle account`? If it's user's account, then you need to assign permission or role to user account. Otherwise, you need to create app and assign permissions to that service principal to read groups.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/257010/discussion-between-sridevi-and-panda).

Comment: Thank you it worked, I was logged in with another service principal which was very identical,

Comment: Hi @Sridevi Do you know how to check group permissions/roles? After listing groups I did reader azurerm_role_assignment ro all the groups. I want to see if the role is assigned to the gropus manually or through command.

Comment: Hi @Panda Please post a new question by including more details with screenshots on your requirement and share link here.

Comment: Here is a question I posted https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78126047/list-microsoft-entra-id-group-role-permissions

Comment: @Panda Check the added answer and let me know if it works!