# List Microsoft Entra ID -> group role/permissions

Tags: azure, terraform, azure-active-directory

I have a below code to give Reader role to a group.

```
data "azuread_group" "example" {
  display_name     = "users-group"
}
resource "azurerm_role_assignment" "example" {
  principal_id         = data.azuread_group.example.id
  role_definition_name = "Reader"
  scope                = "/subscriptions/subscription_id/resourceGroups/${data.azuread_group.example.object_id}"
}
```

I want to list group role assigned through `azurerm_role_assignment` using code, Bash command or through UI

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Portal, you can find the list of roles assigned to Microsoft Entra ID group by visiting ***Azure role assignments*** tab like this:

[image]

To fetch these details via Bash, you can make use of below commands:

```bash
groupId="xxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxx"
az role assignment list --all --query "[?principalId=='$groupId'].{RoleName:roleDefinitionName,Scope:scope, PrincipalName:principalName}" --output table
```

**Response:**

[image]

Comment: Thank you Sridevi, is this line correct? `/subscriptions/subscription_id/resourceGroups/${data.azuread_group.example.object_id` My group is available there but it says `Resource group 'id' could not be found.`

Comment: You need to pass the **name** of resource group in place of `${data.azuread_group.example.object_id`

Comment: I tried giveing name as well it gives same error

Comment: Did you try running the bash script? Or running terraform code?

Comment: I am running terraform code
I replaced with `data.azuread_group.exaple.display_name`

Comment: Please edit your question with your current terraform code. I'll update my answer accordingly with terraform code.

Comment: `data.azuread_group.example.display_name` sorry for the typo

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/257127/discussion-between-sridevi-and-panda).